# How to mock cancel.axios in useEffect using Jest and React testing library

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

**Need:** I would like to pass my test.
**Difficulty:** Mock "axios" on a "useEffect" particularly with "axios.CancelToken".
**Attempts:** I did try to spy on cancelToken but I cannot get it right.

Find bellow my code.

My component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
        const source = cancelToken.source();
        const getName = async () => {
            try {
                    const name = await fetchName(source.token);
                    setName(name ? name : 'noName')
                }
            } catch (error) {
               console.log(error)
            }
        };
         getName()
        return () => {
            source.cancel('axios request cancelled');
        };
    }, []);

     return <h1> Hello {name} </h1> 
}
```

My test:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import axios from 'axios';

    test('MyComponent', async () => {
        const cancelTokenSource: any = { cancel: jest.fn(), token: { reason: { message: 'user canceled' } } };
        jest.spyOn(axios.CancelToken, 'source').mockReturnValueOnce(cancelTokenSource);
        jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce('joe');
        useRouter.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
            query: { cid: 'coffee' },
        }))
        render(<MyComponent />);
       
        const element = await screen.findAllByText('joe');
        expect(element[0]).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
```

Result after passing my test:

```
  ● Testing MyComponent › 

  Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

  59 |     test('MyComponent...', async () => {
  60 |         const cancelTokenSource: any = { cancel: jest.fn(), token: { reason: { message: 'user canceled' } } };
> 61 |         jest.spyOn(axios.CancelToken, 'source').mockReturnValueOnce(cancelTokenSource);
     |              ^
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "axios": "^0.27.2",
     ....
},
    "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "17.0.42",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-preview": "^0.2.8",
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What version of `axios` do you use? Can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Version of axios: "^0.27.2". Thank you for your help.